# Library / Data Structure to store convex polygon with holes

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

I need to create a map of a building.
The area is a convex polygon that has several non-overlapping
convex holes.
As a simplification, the area can also be expressed as a rectangle.
The holes can also be modelled as rectangles.

I first tried to handle it with GEOS, a C++ library that comes
with a low level C API. But it seemed that GEOS is not able
to handle the amount of requests.

What is the best data structure to handle the map?
Perhaps a quadtree? Is there any ready-to-use library
(beyond academical proof-of-concept state)?
The library should be C only (not C++).

Comment: Just as a clarification is the map area a single rectangle and each hole is a single rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of holes is very small (less than 30),
I used an array and did a linear search on this array.
I was underestimating the speed of C, this approach is "fast enough".

Answer (score 2):

Store the map as a list of directed line segments (so that we can determine if we're infront of or behind a segment):

```
struct Segment {
    Pos2 p0;
    Pos2 p1;
    int holeIndex; //Which hole this segment delimits
};
```

Then partition the segments into a [BSP-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning):

```
struct BSPNode {
    Segment partition;
    BSPNode* infront;
    BSPNode* behind;
};
```

Then you can find the hole with this code:

```
int
findHole(BSPNode* node, Pos2 pos) {
    if (!node->behind) { // This node is a leaf
        if (isBehind(pos2, node->partition)) {
            return node->partition->holeIndex;
        } else {
            return -1; //Point is not in a hole
        }
    }
    if (isBehind(pos2, node->partition)) {
        return findHole(node->behind, pos);
    } else {
        return findHole(node->infron, pos);
    }
}

int hole = findHole(root, somePos);
```

If it *is* the case that each hole is a single rectangle you could BSP the set of rectangular holes until you have a single rectangle in each partition.

```
struct BSPNode {
    union {
        Rectangle rectangle; //leaf node
        DirectedLine splitter; //branch node
    };
    BSPNode* infront; // If null indicates this is a leaf node
    BSPNode* behind;
};

int
findHole(BSPNode* node, Pos2 pos) {
    if (!node->behind) { // This node is a leaf
        if (isInside(pos2, node->rectangle)) {
            return node->rectangle->holeIndex;
        } else {
            return -1; //Point is not in a hole
        }
    }
    if (isBehind(pos2, node->splitter)) {
        return findHole(node->behind, pos);
    } else {
        return findHole(node->infron, pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.
I only need to find the polygon (the area or one of the holes) in which a given point is located.

Comment: Do you mean that the holes are numbered in some way and you want to find out in which hole a given point is?

Comment: Yes, exacly. Either an index or even a pointer to the hole (I need its coords and dimensions)